# Can I tell VC2010 to automatically increase precompiled header allocation (same as /Zm) instead of getting c3859?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, compiler-errors

Today I received error c3859 again, and the compiler suggested I used /Zm140.

My question is: How can I tell Visual Studio to automatically increase this memory when required? Is it even possible?

If not - why not? Since the compiler can tell me exactly how much memory it needs - why not simply allocate it by itself?

Answer (score 0):

The flag is there for a reason: the compiler can only determine in hindsight how much memory if would have needed up front.

Comment: And then it can reallocate the required memory and simply continue working - recompile this precompiled header.

Comment: @Asaf: Indeed. And the next build it would compile the same file again twice. But add the `/Zm` flag and all subsequent builds will be fine.

Comment: Of course it would be better if I set the value myself, but changing it for every other header change is tedious at best (not to mention that the value might be different for different configurations and platforms). The compiler can issue a warning and continue building. So is your answer "it cannot be done in Visual Studio"?